# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.Error In Gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle

I have created a new Spring Boot Gradle project. No coding I have done yet. But I am getting the error while running the application as run as Spring Boot. Do I need to add any other dependencies here? or what is the solution for this?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.informationbook'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here I am including the **Console** for reference.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-08-29 10:07:44.398  INFO 18616 --- [           main] c.i.InformationBookApplication           : Starting InformationBookApplication on LAPTOP-I4F37P4O with PID 18616 (C:\Users\mitad\Documents\STS_Workspace\Information-Book\bin\main started by mitad in C:\Users\mitad\Documents\STS_Workspace\Information-Book)
2020-08-29 10:07:44.400  INFO 18616 --- [           main] c.i.InformationBookApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-29 10:07:44.892  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-29 10:07:44.897  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-29 10:07:44.897  INFO 18616 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-29 10:07:44.945  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-29 10:07:44.945  INFO 18616 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 523 ms
2020-08-29 10:07:45.040  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-29 10:07:45.114  WARN 18616 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-08-29 10:07:45.114  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-29 10:07:45.116  INFO 18616 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-29 10:07:45.123  INFO 18616 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-29 10:07:45.124 ERROR 18616 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run Gradle dependency and check dependency tree, console will print

```
Run gradle dependency , console will print your dependency tree,
```

```html
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch -> 2.3.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.(*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.3.3.RELEASE
```

**Spring batch starter is having dependency for Jdbc starter , Either you can provide embedded DB dependency or add database properties in your application properties**

OR

if you don't want database dependency , simply exclude auto configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})